# ThreeJS scene keeps accelerating as it goes on

Tags: javascript, performance, three.js

Me and my friend have been working on a uni assignment - a simple Pacman clone - in ThreeJS (mandatory) and we've had this problem since pretty much the beginning. As the scene keeps running, it starts going faster and faster with each second. It's not like there becomes less stuff to render, everything is pretty much the same.

```
            import * as THREE from '././../three.js-master/build/three.module.js';

    function main() {
        const canvas = document.querySelector('#canva');
        const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas });
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

        /* Camera */
        const fov = 40;
        const aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        const near = 0.1;
        const far = 1000;
        const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
        // I want to go for that angled look
        // Angled enough to show depth, but still have everything important visible
        camera.position.set(0, 65, -45); //Man setting up the camera is fun and not at all painful
        camera.up.set(0, 0, 1);
        camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);

        const scene = new THREE.Scene();

        /* Lights */
        const mainLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, .85);
        mainLight.position.set(0, 20, 0);
        scene.add(mainLight);
        mainLight.castShadow = true;
        mainLight.shadow.mapSize.width = 2048;
        mainLight.shadow.mapSize.height = 2048;

        // const light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1);
        // light.position.set(30, 0, 30);
        // scene.add(light);

        /* Board */
        const boardGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(50, 50);
        const boardMaterial = new THREE.MeshToonMaterial({ color: 0xEEEEEE, side: THREE.DoubleSide });
        const board = new THREE.Mesh(boardGeometry, boardMaterial);
        board.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2; //The board must be placed flat on the x axis
        scene.add(board);

        /* Player */
        const playerBox = new THREE.Box3() // Used to determine collisions

        const playerGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1.5);
        const playerMaterial = new THREE.MeshToonMaterial({ color: 0xAAAAAA });
        const player = new THREE.Mesh(playerGeometry, playerMaterial);

        player.geometry.computeBoundingBox(playerBox);

        /* Players Axes helper */
        const axesHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper(5);
        player.add(axesHelper);

        scene.add(player);

        /* Box helper */
        const playerHelper = new THREE.Box3Helper(playerBox, 0xffff00);
        scene.add(playerHelper);


        /* Enemy #1 */
        const enemy1Box = new THREE.Box3()

        const enemy1Geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
        const enemy1Material = new THREE.MeshToonMaterial({ color: 0x0000ff });
        const enemy1 = new THREE.Mesh(enemy1Geometry, enemy1Material);
        enemy1.position.x = 2

        enemy1.geometry.computeBoundingBox(enemy1Box);

        scene.add(enemy1);

        const enemyHelper = new THREE.Box3Helper(enemy1Box, 0xffff00);
        scene.add(enemyHelper);

        /////////////////////


        /* Cheese */

        const smallCollectibleRadius = .4
        const bigCollectibleRadius = .6

        /* Standard cheese */
        var cheeseList = []
        var cheeseBoxList = []

        const cheeseBox = new THREE.Box3();

        const cheeseGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(smallCollectibleRadius, 100, 100);
        const cheeseMaterial = new THREE.MeshToonMaterial({ color: 0xffff00, emissive: 0xffff00 });
        var cheese = new THREE.Mesh(cheeseGeometry, cheeseMaterial); // Changed const to var so it could be set to null in order to get rid of after collecting
        cheese.position.set(0, 0, 3)
        scene.add(cheese);

        cheese.geometry.computeBoundingBox(cheeseBox);

        const cheeseHelper = new THREE.Box3Helper(cheeseBox, 0xffff00);
        scene.add(cheeseHelper);

        /* SuperCheese */

        const superCheeseGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(bigCollectibleRadius, 100, 100);
        const superCheeseMaterial = new THREE.MeshToonMaterial({ color: 0xcb6600, emissive: 0x0000ff });
        const superCheese = new THREE.Mesh(superCheeseGeometry, superCheeseMaterial);
        superCheese.position.set(0, 0, 5)
        scene.add(superCheese);

        /* Outer wall generation */
        const walls = [];
        const wallGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
        const wallMaterial = new THREE.MeshToonMaterial({ color: 0xAAAAAA });
        //Yes I know the wall being split into blocks might not look good for now
        //Please trust me, it will make more sense later

        //Top
        for (var i = 0; i < 49; i++) {
            const wall = new THREE.Mesh(wallGeometry, wallMaterial);
            wall.position.set(24.5 - i, 0.5, 24.5)
            walls.push(wall);
        }

        //Right
        for (var i = 0; i < 49; i++) {
            const wall = new THREE.Mesh(wallGeometry, wallMaterial);
            wall.position.set(-24.5, 0.5, 24.5 - i)
            walls.push(wall);
        }

        //Bottom
        for (var i = 0; i < 49; i++) {
            const wall = new THREE.Mesh(wallGeometry, wallMaterial);
            wall.position.set(-24.5 + i, 0.5, -24.5)
            walls.push(wall);
        }

        //Left
        for (var i = 0; i < 49; i++) {
            const wall = new THREE.Mesh(wallGeometry, wallMaterial);
            wall.position.set(24.5, 0.5, -24.5 + i)
            walls.push(wall);
        }
        //Tried to do the four of them as a single double loop
        //Might try again later

        for (var i = 0; i < walls.length; i++) scene.add(walls[i]);
        //////////////////////////




        function makeCoins(num, cheeseList_t = cheeseList, cheeseBoxList_t = cheeseBoxList) { //I know these names break the convention.
            const smallCollectibleRadius = .4
            const bigCollectibleRadius = .6

            for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                console.log("I'm a fake cheese!")

                const cheeseBox = new THREE.Box3();

                const cheeseGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(smallCollectibleRadius, 100, 100);
                const cheeseMaterial = new THREE.MeshToonMaterial({ color: 0xffff00, emissive: 0xffff00 });
                var cheese = new THREE.Mesh(cheeseGeometry, cheeseMaterial);
                cheese.position.set(0, 0, (6 + i))
                cheese.userData.idd = i // it's in a dict form, {"idd":i}
                scene.add(cheese);

                cheese.geometry.computeBoundingBox(cheeseBox);

                const cheeseHelper = new THREE.Box3Helper(cheeseBox, 0xffff00);
                scene.add(cheeseHelper);

                cheeseList_t.push(cheese)
                cheeseBoxList_t.push(cheeseBox)
            }

        }

        makeCoins(2) // IT WORKS, HOLY COW
        console.log(cheeseList[1])





        function checkCollision(box) {
            /* Code sucks but works and will by changed in future anyway */
            var collision = playerBox.intersectsBox(box);
            if (collision == true) {
                return true
            }
        }

        function collect(item) {
            /* TODO: Collecting cheeses */
        }

        var points = 0;

        function updatePoints(amount) {
            points += amount
        }

        document.addEventListener("keypress", function (event) {
            /* Additional player movement's listener that doesn't throw 2137 msgs in the console.
            It would be great to make it the only one player movement's listener */

            if (checkCollision(enemy1Box)) {
                /**/
                console.log("You bumped into enemy1!")
            }

            if (cheese !== null && !('consumed' in cheese.userData) && checkCollision(cheeseBox)) {
                /* This will go to collect() function once finished */
                console.log("Yummy cheese!")
                scene.remove(cheese)
                cheese.userData.consumed = true // good to know there is this userData feature
                cheese = null
                updatePoints(1)
            }

            /* For testing purposes */
            var coinBox = cheeseBoxList[0]
            if (checkCollision(coinBox)){
                console.log("HOLY GUACAMOLE, IT WORKS") // IT REALLY DOES!
            }



        });


        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        /* Render stuff */
        function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
            const canvas = renderer.domElement;
            const width = canvas.clientWidth;
            const height = canvas.clientHeight;
            const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
            if (needResize) {
                renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
            }
            return needResize;
        }

        function render(time) {
            time *= 0.001;
            const speed = 0.0005
            const rotSpeed = 0.00005
            const dir = new THREE.Vector3();

            if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
                const canvas = renderer.domElement;
                camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            }

            /* Updating boxes */
            enemy1Box.copy(enemy1.geometry.boundingBox).applyMatrix4(enemy1.matrixWorld);
            playerBox.copy(player.geometry.boundingBox).applyMatrix4(player.matrixWorld);
            if (cheese !== null && !('consumed' in cheese.userData)) {
                cheeseBox.copy(cheese.geometry.boundingBox).applyMatrix4(cheese.matrixWorld);
            }

            /* TEST */

            var coin = cheeseList[0]
            var coinBox = cheeseBoxList[0]

            coinBox.copy(coin.geometry.boundingBox).applyMatrix4(coin.matrixWorld); // HOLY COW, IT SEEMS TO WORK


            /* I'm afraid it'll lag everything but I can't think of better way of doing this;
               this MUST be in render(), otherwise it won't update, but for loop in HERE... ugh
               I will not run this. I care for my new PC. I don't want it to burn. I don't care for yours tho. Sorry not sorry, mate

               IT'S NOT FINISHED YET, DON'T THINK OF RUNNING THIS

            for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                coin = coinList[i]
                coinBox = coinBoxList[i]

                coinBox.copy(coin.geometry.boundingBox).applyMatrix4(coin.matrixWorld);
            }
            */

            document.getElementById("points").innerHTML = points

            document.addEventListener("keypress", function (event) {
                if (event.keyCode == 119) { //W going forward
                    if (checkCollision(enemy1Box)) {
                        console.log("Can't go any further!") // TODO: Delete in the future
                    } else {
                        player.getWorldDirection(dir);
                        player.position.addScaledVector(dir, speed);
                    }
                }
                if (event.keyCode == 115) { //S going backward
                    player.getWorldDirection(dir);
                    player.position.addScaledVector(dir, -speed);
                }

                if (event.keyCode == 97) { //A left rotation
                    player.rotation.y += rotSpeed
                }

                if (event.keyCode == 100) { //D right rotation
                    player.rotation.y -= rotSpeed
                }


            });

            renderer.render(scene, camera);

            requestAnimationFrame(render);
        }

        requestAnimationFrame(render);
    }

    main();
```

Answer (score 0):

You’re adding keypress event listeners inside your render loop. This means that by the time 60 frames have gone by, you’ll have 60 event listeners doing the same thing. That’s why you’re seeing your scene speeding up: the more frames have passed, the more event listeners you’ve added.

Just initialize those events outside the render loop, and you’ll see the issue go away.